# Change page layout

Tags: sidebar

I am using a theme called "seller" and in the product category pages as well as the shop page the sidebar doesnt appear. After searching different ways to add it i found out that it's because the pages layout is set to full width, no sidebar. The question is, how do i modify the layout so that it is not full width? Actually, being the same as the other pages created by user. The shop page has a workaround (create a new page and in the menu add the product categories as under this new page) but for the prod categ this cant work. I have some knowledge of html5 and css and browsed through the .php files and css, but i dont  know where to modify, because it's a little over my coding skills. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Template responsible for product category is archive-product.php. Woocommerce is looking for the file first in your theme folder (yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php) and if it's not there, it's taking one from plugin folder. The plugin calls for sidebar with `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' ); ?>`